# ¿Cómo agrupar rutas para el frontend en CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php7, codeigniter-4, routes

**CONTEXTO:** PHP 7.4, CodeIgniter 4.1.3

**PROBLEMA:** Imposible agrupar rutas para el front. En todos los casos salta un 404 para esa ruta.

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO**

Todos los grupos de rutas que tengo funcionan bien, por ejemplo este:

```
$routes->group('/auth', ['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Auth'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('login', 'Auth::create');
    $routes->get('logout', 'Auth::logout', ["filter" => "myauth"]);
    $routes->get('welcome', 'Auth::index', ["filter" => "myauth"]);
});
```

Pero si quiero agrupar las rutas del frontend, sólo funciona la ruta que hace referencia a la home (/), todas las demás no funcionan (en este caso *abc*), siempre salta el error 404.

```
$routes->group('', ['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Front'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('/', 'Frontend::index');
    $routes->get('/abc', 'Frontend::abc');
});
```

Ya intenté poner el slash en el primer parámetro de group(), pero igual no funciona.

**CÓMO HE INTENTADO SOLUCIONAR EL PROBLEMA**

La cosa se soluciona si agrego las rutas por separado (no agrupándolas).

```
$routes->add('/', 'Front\Frontend::index');
$routes->add('/abc', 'Front\Frontend::abc');
$routes->add('/def', 'Front\Frontend::def');
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué no me funciona la agrupación cuando se trata del front?

Answer (score 0):

Como yo lo tengo me funciona bien
el nombre de grupo deber ser quien lo identifique, falla con solo dejar ''

```
$routes->group('prueba',['namespace'=>'App\Controllers\front'], function($routes)
{
    $routes->get('/', 'Prueba::index');
    $routes->post('buscar/(:any)','Prueba::buscar/$1');
    $routes->post('confirmar/(:any)','Prueba::confirmar/$1');
});
```